# jQuery trigger change without losing focus?

Tags: jquery, bind

I have a script, like this:

```
$(".b").hide();
$(".uid").bind("change", function() {
    if($(this).val().length>0) {
        $(".b").show();
    } else {
        $(".b").hide();
    }
});
```

This works as you would expect, but, to get ".b" to show, I have to leave focus of ".uid".  Is there any way I can get "." to show without clicking outside of ".uid"?  It's a submit button that is hidden until something is entered into the text field and I want it to show up as soon as something is entered into the field without having to click out of the field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use `keyup` instead:

```
$(".b").hide();
$(".uid").on("keyup", function() {
    if($(this).val().length>0) {
        $(".b").show();
    } else {
        $(".b").hide();
    }
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/YCGw9/

Comment: Or perhaps keyup _and_ change so that when a user does a drag'n'drop or paste without using the keyboard it will still work.

Comment: @nnnnnn: ... and mouse events - in case of right click -> paste. It all depends on how solid OP wants it to be.